# trigger click on mouse find previous i element

Tags: jquery, triggers

I have a page where i use an i element to add a row to form:

jquery:

```
 $('body').on('click','.newTask',function(){
    var id= $(this).attr('data-tableId');
   //ajax call to get 
        <tr>
          <td><input type='text'></td>
          <td><input type='text'></td>
          <td><input type='text' class='last'></td>
        </tr>
    success:function(result){
         $('#newTableRow_'+id).append(result);
   //
 });
```

the tables:

```
<table id='1'>
  <tr>
     <td><i class="bi bi-plus-circle-fill fa-1x icon-green newTask" data-tableId='1'>Add Task</i></td>
  </tr>
  <tbody id='newTableRow_1'></tbody>
</table>

<table id='2'>
  <tr>
     <td><i class="bi bi-plus-circle-fill fa-1x icon-green newTask" data-tableId='2'>Add Task</i></td>
  </tr>
  <tbody id='newTableRow_2'></tbody>
</table>
```

in which when this is clicked, newTask adds a new row of elements to the form.

```
<tr>
    <td><input type='text'></td>
    <td><input type='text'></td>
    <td><input type='text' class='last'></td>
</tr>
```

when the user tabs out of the element with class "last", i am trying to trigger the newTask click so a new row will be automatically added and user doesnt have to click the i.  the below code fires, (the alert shows when i focusout), but the trigger.click is not happening.

```
    $('body').on('focusout','.last',function(){
        alert('clicked');
        $(this).closest('.newTask').trigger('click');

         //I have also tried 
            $(this).find('.newTask').trigger('click');
    });
```

*note - there could be many tables on this page that have the .newTask cell.

Comment: Try and add the full table. What you added isn't very helpful

Comment: Do you have multiple "add task" buttons?   If only one, then just `$(".newTask").click()` should suffice.  **after edit** - yes you do - `.closest()` goes *up* the DOM tree (it's like `.parents().filter(selector).first()` (or .last() depending on how you look at it)).   So `$(this).closest("table").find(".newTask").click()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is adding an ID to <i> element and trigger click on element selected by id.

```js
$('body').on('focusout', '.last', function() {
  alert('clicked');
  $('#add-task-button').find('.newTask').trigger('click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><i id="add-task-button" class="bi bi-plus-circle-fill fa-1x icon-green newTask">Add Task</i></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type='text'></td>
    <td><input type='text'></td>
    <td><input type='text' class='last'></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your could would no work, as the ID and the class are both on the `<i>` so would need to be `$("#add-task-button.newTask")` (obviously pointless so just `$("#add-task-button");`   But OP has *updated* question to confirm there are multliple new task buttons.

Comment: this worked! for bonus points,  how can i focus on the first input that has been added by the ajax call after ajax fires?